# How to pull in upstream changes into a fork using Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I've forked a Mercurial repository, and now I want to pull the changes from the main repository into my fork.  If this were git, I would do something like...

```
git remote add upstream <url>
git pull upstream master
```

How do I do this sort of thing in Mercurial?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you cloned the repository from the one you want to pull changes from, you can simply do:

```
hg pull
```

If you cloned the repository from another repository, you can:

```
hg pull <location of repository to pull from>
```

You'll then need to update your working copy:

```
hg update
```

That's the basics, anyway.  More details are available in the [Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/)

Answer (score 50):

You could also modify your hgrc file in your repo

```
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/<my_user>/<my_repo>
upstream = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/<other_user>/<other_repo>
```

Then you can do

```
hg pull upstream
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the pull command?

```
hg pull http://master.com/master
```

If that does not work, please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

You could also modify your hgrc file in your repo to use the special path names default and default-push.

```
default-push = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/<my_user>/<my_repo>
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/<other_user>/<other_repo>
```

Then you can pull from upstream (aka default) with

```
hg pull
```

and push to fork (aka default-push) with

```
hg push
```

Comment: If other users make changes to `<my_repo>` wouldn't this break? This would only work on a solo-user repo, am I right?